# sha256(str + "something") при знании sha256(str) и "something"

Tags: криптография, sha256

Дан хэш некоторой неизвестной строки - `sha256(str)`

Так же есть строка которая нам известна, например - `"something"`

Можно ли найти `sha256(str + "something")`? Мне интересна именно надежность `sha256(str + "something")` не сильно ли упроститься задача для потенциального взломщика (если вообще упроститься) при знании `sha256(str)` и строки `"something"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте допустим, что такой метод существует и оно "быстрее". Тогда `sha256("123")` можно было бы заменить на `sha256("1") @ sha256("2") @ sha256("3")` (`@` - это мифическая операция объединения). А это бы сразу сделало перебор сильно-сильно быстрее. И скорее всего об этом уже знали. И хеши бы <strike>ломались</strike> подбирались сильно быстрее.

поэтому, если кто то владеет указанной в вопросе методикой, то ему и не нужно знать строку something:).